# Deciding about dimensionality reduction, classification and clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

Could you please help me to understand it because I'm not sure if I got it correctly.

Let's say I have a dataset, of persons, with 100 features, various characteristics like height, weight, age, etc. I want to classify if are normal or abnormal. By abnormal I mean if a 20 years old man is 170cm and 150kg to identify it as abnormal.

Should I use Self Organising Map to reduce the dimensionality (these 100 features) and then K-means to classify them into normal and abnormal? Is that a correct approach? Or I can use just K-NN to classify them into normal - abnormal without any dimensionality reduction?

How many features can I use with K-NN? All the examples I've found so far use just two.

And if later I'd like to find why this person has included into the abnormal class how can I find that this happened because of these two features, his weight according to his height?

Comment: Better to ask at -  http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or you can even use PCA with K-Means, etc. I'm afraid answer this question is too broad and cannot be answer with the scope of SO. But as an advice, you ought analyze and study your data before jumping into the algorithm design. It's a common data science mistake. Data Analysis will help you decided whether you actually need dimension reduction, feature engineering, classification or clustering, maybe with kmeans, or random forests, etc.

Comment: @eliasah Can you please tell me how many features can I use with K-NN? Can I use K-NN with hundred features?

Comment: Well, theoretically, you can but if you have read my previous comment well, you shouldn't !

Comment: Please do not cross-post. Post only on the one most appropriate site. Since this is **not a programming question**, DS was the better choice: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9724/924

Comment: Also stop your obsession about KNN (which still is not kMeans! KNN requires labels!) and dimensionality reduction, and instead try to **understand your data**. As you may have heard, data science should be *data-driven*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have labels for each sample - it's unsupervised learning task, maybe outlier detection/anomality detection.

I think in your case you just have to fit multivariate gaussian distribution to your dataset and assume that new sample is not normal if p(x) (where p is fitted normal distribution) is less than some threshold.
Look here also: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#outlier-detection